# Remote Facade pattern vs Facade pattern

Tags: design-patterns, facade

Besides the interface of `Remote Facade pattern` being more *coarse-grained* and clients calling this interface being *remote* rather than local, are there any other differences between the two patterns?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you referring to a `Remote` interface like Java's RMI?  I don't think that is a `facade` but actually a `proxy` pattern implementation.

the Remote forwards all calls (hidden from the user via the proxy pattern) to a different machine.  This hides from the user the fact that the work is not being done locally.

`Facade` pattern usually simplifies a complicated interface to a more simplified version (like a substituting a complicated control panel with a different control panel with only the a few of the most used buttons).  If you really need the more complicated version, you can still use the old more complicated controls instead.

**EDIT**
After you pointed out that you are referring to Marin Fowler's `Remote Facade` I will explain further:

Fowler's `Remote Facade` is not just `Remote` + `Facade` patterns.  There is also a extra reasoning behind the simplifications the facade uses.

Instead of just simplifying complicated methods or removing under used methods from the facade. `RemoteFacade` is explicitly used to combine several common methods in the "unfacaded" interface to  reduce latency and network traffic.

Since `Remote` calls will go over the network (using Java's RMI etc) there is a lot of overhead to convert the method call into a message to pass over the network.  It takes time for the message to go over the network and get a message back and unmarshal the response etc.  There might also be security layers checking and intercepting the traffic as well. All add to the amount of time and effort to call the remote method.

`RemoteFacade` combines several common methods into a single network message.  So using Fowler's example from his book, if you have an interface for Address with separate setters for setCity() setZipcode(), setStreet().  That would be 3 remote calls to go over the network.  Instead `RemoteFacade` turns that into 1 method setAddress(street, city, zip) which will only require 1 networked message passed and therefore it should take less time to invoke.

Comment: I was referring to Fowlers' pattern: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/remoteFacade.html, which I don't think is the same as Java's RMI

Comment: @dkatzel So according to current language, I should make 1 WebService for my client to update City, ZipCode and Street and instead of 3 WebServices for each. Is that what it translates to? Or it is just a convenient object for the clients to wrap the fine-grained WebServices into coarse-grained method which I don't think because it will still end up in 3 network calls.